WII U Single disc not working
I have a WII U that we bought used several years ago, it's always worked well, but recently I have one disc that it won't recognize (Breath of the Wild). Just the last 2 weeks it has gotten more and more difficult to it to recognize the disc. Now it won't recognize it at all (says Invalid disk). All other discs that I put in seem to work (whether WII U disc, or WII disc) it is just BOTW that isn't working. The disc is in great shape, and we've cleaned it. I'm wondering if anyone knows what's going on?
The game pad gives me error code: 150-2031. The disc could not be read, it might be dirty. But like I said, every other disc I've tried is working and the disc has been cleaned and looks like it's in great condition.
I haven't tried cleaning the drive, I'm not sure if I can just use a DVD drive cleaner, the actual ones for the WII U were like $50, so I didn't want to go with those just yet.
Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

I haven’t looked for a long time, but physical games often used to contain small print in the back of the manual saying you could return the game and get replacement media for it for a nominal fee (I got a new copy of a game for about £8  that cost probably £30 or £40 this way). Worth looking if that’s still a thing.

I looked, and Nintendo's official site says they no longer provide replacement disks for WII U games. ☹

Maybe the disk is getting worn out. This happens often to games we love, the disc gets worn out. Also at the hole in the center of the disc, there is a bar code that the Wii U needs to read so it can decode the information of the disk. Double check that.
Read the operations Manual or the Health and Safety Manual in the Wii U for help.

If I can remember, you should start with a damp cloth, and start from the hole, and wipe outwards. That is what the manual says.

If this doesn't work, you might just have to purchase a new BOTW disc.
